# Adding values by duplicated name

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-log-analytics

I want to generate Azure log analytics query using powershell.

But I'm stuck on a strange problem. Not sure why, but it shows duplicated entries for few VMs.

My goal is to generate report of up time values for each VM. Here's my code:

```php
$startime = '2019-08-01';
$endtime = '2019-08-31';
$queryResults = Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId "..." -Query "let start_time=startofday(datetime('$startime'));
    let end_time=endofday(datetime('$endtime'));
    Heartbeat
    | where TimeGenerated > start_time and TimeGenerated < end_time
    | summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, start_time), Computer
    | extend available_per_hour=iff(heartbeat_per_hour>0, true, false)
    | summarize total_available_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by Computer 
    " 

$output = $QueryResults.Results | foreach-object {
    [PSCustomObject]
        @{
            "VM Name" = ($_.Computer.split('.')[0]).ToUpper()
            "VM Uptime (in Hours)" = $_.total_available_hours
        }
    }
```

In `$output` variable I see multiple entries for few VMs. It would be easy to just remove the duplicates, but I want to sum the values of up time for each VM occurence in order to avoid duplicate entries, but having them added at the same time.

Duplicates happen because in query result, some VMs are shown both w/out and with FQDN with different up time values, hence the split command in foreach-object command. Not sure why that happens too.

Comment: can you just use for-each again in the $output, then sum the up_time for the vm which has same names?

Comment: do multiple computers have the same name on different domains? e.g. "MyComputer.domain1.com" and "MyComputer.domain2.com"? your ```($_.Computer.split('.')[0]).ToUpper()``` would reduce them both to "MYCOMPUTER"... Maybe remove the ```split``` and generate the report with full names and see if the duplicates persist...

Comment: @Ivan Yang I could, but how? I don't how to write a condition, which will sum uptime values based on vm name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding the issue.

According to your code, seems that if the computer_1 name is pc_1, and computer_2 name is pc_1.azure.com, then you think them as the same computer? so you want to sum the uptime of the 2 computers together? Like pc_1 uptime is 10, pc_1.azure.com uptime is 20, the result should be vmName:pc_1 => uptime:30? right?

If that's the case, you have 2 ways to achieve that. The first way is re-write the query in kusto, the 2nd way is re-write powershell code.

Here, I just re-write your kusto query by split the computer name, like below:

```
    let start_time=startofday(datetime('$startime'));
    let end_time=endofday(datetime('$endtime'));
    Heartbeat
    | where TimeGenerated > start_time and TimeGenerated < end_time
    | extend aa=split(Computer, ".")
    | extend bb=array_slice(aa, 0, 0)
    | extend my_Computer=strcat_array(bb,"") 
    | summarize heartbeat_per_hour=count() by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, start_time), my_Computer
    | extend available_per_hour=iff(heartbeat_per_hour>0, true, false)
    | summarize total_available_hours=countif(available_per_hour==true) by my_Computer
```

The screenshot below shows the effect of split computer name:

[image]

The 2nd way to use powershell, like op mentioned in the comment:

```
$output = $output | Group-Object -Property "VM Name" | Select-Object -unique Name, @{L="VM Uptime (in Hours)";E={($_.group | Measure-Object -Property "VM Uptime (in Hours)" -Sum).sum}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! I managed to fix it by adding this line to my powershell script: 
$output = $output | Group-Object -Property "VM Name" | Select-Object -unique Name, @{L="VM Uptime (in Hours)";E={($_.group | Measure-Object -Property "VM Uptime (in Hours)" -Sum).sum}}